# "chrome.tabs.query" can't Execution my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

```
    function onWindowLoad() {
  chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    tabUrl  = tabs[0].url;
    alert(tabUrl);//taburl is Successfully displayed in my browser
    $("#txtUrl").val(tabUrl);//This line of code is not implemented
    alert("hello");//cant't alert hello
});

window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

please help me :I want to get the url to my page, but after running the code and nothing happens,How to deal with it?

Comment: web extensions don't have access to jquery

Comment: If this code runs in the popup, you need to include jquery.js locally in the extension.